# Did Karl Marx openly advocate violence? (or oppose it?)

Tags: social-history, communism, social-class, dictatorship

Whether Marxism is inherently violent is often a point of contention. The supporters of Marxism often claim that the violence of the Communist regimes of the XX-th century was of their own making, and not inherently grounded in Marx' work.

On the one hand, Marx speaks of violence as early as in *The Communist Manifesto*, but there it could be blamed on the oppressing classes, reluctant to abandon their privileges - indeed, the use of violence for suppressing social movements was certainly commonplace in Marx' times.

There is implicit violence in the notion of the *dictatorship of the proletariat*, which means limiting the rights of all the other classes (peasantry, intellectuals, small bourgeoisie) while their way of life is being destroyed, to pave the way to the new society. While one could trace the later Communist violence to this, there is some deniability in Marx being not explicit about what such a dictatorship entailed or perhaps, being too naïve about the human nature to foresee that.

The place where I have seen the two notions to meet is in Isaiah Berlin's chapter in the Paris Commune (*"Red Terror Doctor"* in [*Karl Marx: His Life and Environment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Marx:_His_Life_and_Environment)), where he describes the widespread outrage at the Communards' terror, while Marx took the opposite position, criticizing them for not being ruthless enough. Berlin cites it as the principle reason for the demise of the First International:

> Presently, as supplies began to give out, and the condition of
> the besieged grew more desperate, terror developed: proscriptions
> began, men and women were condemned and executed, many
> of them certainly guiltless, and few deserving of death. Among
> those executed was the archbishop of Paris, who had been held
> as a hostage against the army at Versailles. **The rest of Europe
> watched the monstrous events with growing indignation and
> disgust. The Communards seemed even to enlightened opinion,
> even to old and tried friends of the people like Louis Blanc and
> Mazzini, to be a band of criminal lunatics dead to the appeal of
> humanity, social incendiaries pledged to destroy all religion and
> all morality, men driven out of their minds by real and imaginary
> wrongs, scarcely responsible for their enormities.**
>
> [...]
>
> While he approved many of the measures of the Commune,
> **he blamed it for not being ruthless and radical enough**: nor did
> he believe in its aim of creating immediate social and economic
> equality.

(emphasis is mine.)

I couldn't find any more evidence for Marx open support for violence, but this not necessarily the evidence of absence: most of those studying and writing about Marx are sharing to some extent the Marxist ideology and often gloss over the Communist violence. E.g., David McLellan in [*Marxism after Marx*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1403997276) barely even speaks of *"excesses"*: his harshest words about Stalin is that the latter *didn't give enough importance to individual*.

To formulate the question more concisely:

- Is Marx on the record openly supporting violence?
- Is Marx on the record openly opposing violence?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147361/discussion-on-question-by-roger-vadim-did-karl-marx-openly-advocate-violence-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Far too long. And it sounds like you have already decided that the answer is Marx believed in violence. I'm not even saying you're wrong, but there is no point to a question which you have already decided the answer to.

Comment: @NeMo I am looking for a confirmation or disproval using actual Marx writing/quotes, not just ssking other's opinion. I think this is very much in line with SE mission.

Answer (score 9):

There's a trivial part and an unanswerable part to the question. The trivial part - did Marx think that a violent revolution was the only way to bring a better society into being? Yep, he did. It's been pointed out correctly that the American revolutionaries also believed this. No American politician in the 19th century was saying that letter-writing or civil disobedience would have dislodged Lord North back in 1776.

Less obviously, but just as inescapably, this was also true in Britain, where Marx spent most of his life. The political system there was the product of the Revolution of 1688 - this established parliamentary supremacy, which from about 1760 virtually all of the ruling class and most of the commoners believed in (that is, Jacobites went from a sizable minority to a tiny fringe).

Like the American war of independence, the post-1688 settlement in Britain was achieved *violently* and *illegally*. We could say that the rulers of both countries 'believed in violence' as a way to achieve positive change. And both they and their predecessors also believed in violence as a way to *prevent* changes which they did not want.

Despite being in some respects the least despotic of the wealthy countries during Marx's life, Britain, France and the United States were not yet liberal democracies. In modern times it is possible in these countries to effect major political change without killing people. Nobody thought that this was remotely feasible in Marx's time.

The first part, above, is trite.

The second part, whether Marx would have approved of the murderous rule of Lenin and his imitators, is unanswerable. Marx died in 1883, Lenin came to power in 1917.

Intellectual honesty demands I point out that Lenin 'believed in violence' as a way of maintaining power to a far greater extent than Thiers or Gladstone or Cleveland did. There's no doubt Lenin 'believed in violence', and not the 19th century kid glove version where numbers of political executions are measured in the dozens or hundreds. Under Lenin they numbered thousands.

Asking whether Marx would have approved of the Cheka is like asking if Edmund Burke would have approved of General Franco (150,000 victims). Undoubtedly many of Burke's heirs did, and many didn't. Burke was not there to ask.

Likewise, there are many political parties today that claim to follow some version of Marx's ideas. Many of those operate in democracies and have participated in coalition governments - such as the current government of Spain. No gulags yet.

Undoubtedly many political parties accurately track Lenin's interpretation of Marx, which means that, yes, they believe in violence.

Which interpretation of Marx's beliefs is right? That's a question for discussing, not answering. You certainly can't divine it by what Marx said or didn't say about revolutions.

Comment: +1 interesting angle. Note that Ferdinand Lassalle did advocate for achieving Socialism peacefully - the point of view reflected in the Gotha Program, much criticized by Marx (*Critique of the Gotha program*). Also, the *dictatorship of the proletariat* as a method of government was not Lenin's invention, even the idea of the party as the *revolutionary vanguard* apparently emerges already in Marx.

Comment: Words are slippery. In the 1920s a (conservative) government in Portugal established a 'national dictatorship'. A supposedly temporary emergency measure. It didn't turn out that way, but the fact that they used the word means it didn't automatically communicate 'I am evil' at the time Marx chose it.

Comment: If the SPD (writers of the Gotha programme) thought they were going to achieve universal suffrage, a living wage and all the rest of it without anyone getting hurt, unfortunately they were wrong and Marx turned out to be right. It took thousands dead in the German Revolution to achieve that, to say nothing of the millions dead in WW1 which precipitated it. In Marx's time the only peaceful revolutionaries were useless hippies like Robert Owen - they had a long track record of failure. From our point of view nonviolence can succeed, because we live in a democratic country. Marx didn't.

Comment: I don't see how *"Marx turned out to be right"* in Germany or anywhere else in western world, but that's beyond the question.

Comment: He turned out to be right when he said that fundamental political change in Germany would not be achieved by nonviolent means. It wasn't.

Comment: This is just not serious - you present Marx a kind of Nostradamus, with predictions so vague that any historical event can be fit into them.

Comment: Perhaps you now see why I said the second part of your question could only be discussed, not answered - and why it's unfit for stack exchange.

Comment: No, the question can be answered by quotes - but for that one should have actually read Marx. I don't see that in your answer.

Comment: No amount of quotes is going to prove or disprove the statement that Marx would have supported regimes such as Lenin's. We can't know - he was dead

Comment: That's not the question. The question is about what he actually said and what he didn't say

Comment: +1 for citing Burke vs Franco as a comparison to Marx vs Lenin, and avoiding the over-debatted Godwin point of Nietzsche vs Hitler.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I try to avoid bringing in That Guy unless it's the best possible way to make the point you're going for.

Answer (score -1):

Marx believed, even in democracies, that violent revolutionary terror was required. This due to the fact that Marxist revolutionaries would never achieve a majority thru democratic means, thus effecting change toward a utopian communist paradise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).